# AWS SSO Implemenation with Custom SAML 2.0 Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have create a Custom SAML 2.0 Applications and assigned user to it. When i tried to login with that user. it shows like below image. Can anyone help me out with this problem. The ACS url also dosen't got the saml response.
[image: Issue Image]